# How to point to specific commit on referenced repository for Azure Pipelines build

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Our team uses an Azure DevOps Pipeline that runs based on the code in another repository. We have a yaml file written within our repository that references the other repository for our Azure DevOps Pipeline as follows:

```
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: e2e_fx
    type: github
    name: Azure/iot-sdks-e2e-fx
    ref: refs/heads/master
    endpoint: 'GitHub OAuth'

jobs:
- template: vsts/templates/jobs-gate-c.yaml@e2e_fx
```

Currently the yaml points to the head of master for the other repository, so if a new commit is added to that remote repository then it will be pointed to. I want to be able to reference a specific commit from the repository referenced. How can I do that?

For reference, I've already tried copying the specific commit I want to reference and pasting it where `refs/heads/master` is right now, but that gave an error.

Comment: Do you want that Azure DevOps will bring only specific commit to the build pipeline?

Comment: exactly. Only a specific commit of the referenced repository.

Comment: Ok, see my answer :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Checkout a repository and specify a commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75076229/checkout-a-repository-and-specify-a-commit)

Answer (score 5):

Currently there is no option to do it out-of-the-box in the `.yaml` file.

You can configure the `.yaml` to [not sync sources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/github?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#dont-sync-sources), then the build will not download the repository, and in the beginning of the build add a Command Line task to download only the commit yo want.

To tell the .`yaml` not to sync sources in the `steps:` add `- checkout: none`:

```
steps:
- checkout: none # Don't sync sources
```

Comment: `and in the beginning of the build add a Command Line task to download only the commit yo want.` - How can I do that ?

Comment: @Сергей with `git clone` commands (and use `sparse checkout` for specific commits).

Comment: If I use `steps:- checkout` command in yaml, then clone some repo, then use `sparse checkout` for specific commit and push some changes. In this case, the pipeline builds based on commit before change or new commit ?

Comment: If you clone the whole repo so the pipelines is based on the latest commit, I think the sparse checkout is for specific files, not commits, my mistake. search how to get specific commit in git.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is to create a new branch from the commit that you want to reference  and use `ref:`

Answer (score 0):

- Disable Shallow Fetch (download all commits) with `fetchDepth: 0`
- Then checkout the needed one

```
steps:
  - checkout: self
    displayName: 'Checkout self'

  # Azure DevOps agent supports HTTPS with Git, SSH not yet supported. Cloning it locally via 'checkout:'.
  # https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/pipeline-options-for-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#what-protocols-can-the-build-agent-use-with-git
  - checkout: 'git://<YourOrg>/<your-reponame>'
    fetchDepth: 0
    displayName: 'Checkout your-reponame repo'

  # Replace SSH Git repo with a local one
  - bash: |
      git -C <your-reponame> checkout <commit>
    workingDirectory: "<your-reponame>"
    displayName: 'Checkout <your-reponame> to specific commit'
```

Other `checkout:` params are listed in the documentation
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/steps-checkout