# Checkout a repository and specify a commit

Tags: git, azure-devops, yaml, repository

I have a repository in which I have a YAML file with the following code:

```
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: repoxyz
    type: git
    name: OneXXXXXX/public
    ref: develop

stages:

- template: buildone.yml@repoxyz
  parameters:
    repoToCheckout: repoxyz
    checkoutPath: '$(Build.BuildNumber)'
- template: buildtwo.yml@repoxyz
  parameters:
    repoToCheckout: repoxyz
    checkoutPath: '$(Build.BuildNumber)'
```

I'm trying to checkout repoxyz using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops approach. When I do the deployment using this YAML file, it always checks out the latest commit from 'develop' branch. Is it possible to specify a commit while checking out the repo so that during deployment, it will use that commit instead of latest commit?

UPDATE:

I added some steps as suggested in the solution and I see the log showing "Head is now at the specified commit" however, I see the changes from the latest commit deployed.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can specify a branch https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/resources-repositories-repository?view=azure-pipelines

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to specify a commit while checking out the repo so that during deployment, it will use that commit instead of latest commit?

Refer to this doc about YAML schema: [resources.repositories.repository definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/resources-repositories-repository?view=azure-pipelines)

```
repositories:
- repository: string # Required as first property. Alias for the specified repository.  ([-_A-Za-z0-9]*)
  endpoint: string # ID of the service endpoint connecting to this repository. 
  trigger: trigger # CI trigger for this repository, no CI trigger if skipped (only works for Azure Repos).
  name: string # repository name (format depends on `type`); does not accept variables. 
  type: string # Type of repository: `git`, `github`, `githubenterprise`, and `bitbucket`. 
  ref: string # ref name to checkout; defaults to 'refs/heads/main'. The branch checked out by default whenever the resource trigger fires. Does not accept variables.
```

I am afraid that there is no out-of-box method can specify commit in repositories resources of YAML Pipeline. It only supports to define branch for the time being.

**Workaround:**

You can use git command to reset the head of the branch. Then the source repo will be rolled back to the corresponding version.

Here is an example:

```
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: repoxyz
    type: git
    name: 123/Repo90
    ref: test
   

trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
- checkout: self
  fetchDepth: 0
- checkout: repoxyz
  fetchDepth: 0

- script: |
   cd $(build.sourcesdirectory)/Repo90

   git reset --hard commitid
```

**Note:** The default fetch depth is 1. You need to set it to 0, then it will checkout all related commits. `fetchDepth: 0`

On the other hand, I can fully understand your requirements.  You can create a suggestion ticket in [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/AzureDevOps/suggest) to report your requirement.

Comment: Can you please explain what these steps indicate?

Comment: There is no out-of-box method to define commit in Repo resources. So we can use git command to roll back the target commit. Then the checkout repo will use the target commit instead of the latest one.

Comment: Should I add reset command in buildone.yml@repoxyz and buildtwo.yml@repoxyz

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly point to a commit, but you can point to a tag that is a direct link to a commit ;)

```
- repository: repoxyz
  type: git
  name: OneXXXXXX/public
  ref: refs/tags/<your-tag-name>
```

To create a tag:

- go to your commits list
- on the 3 dots at the end of the line of the commit (commit's menu), you'll have "Create tag"
  [image]

Bonus: you can move (delete/recreate) your tag to another commit without having to update your pipeline :)